# How to fix the error 'alpha' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/styles' when using Skeleton in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI and I am getting a nasty error on Ubuntu with the Skeleton component.
While on Windows I do not get this error and everything works fine, on Ubuntu I am getting the following error:

```
./node_modules/@material-ui/lab/esm/Skeleton/Skeleton.js
Attempted import error: 'alpha' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/styles'.
```

The import is taken from the official docs:

```
import Skeleton from '@material-ui/lab/Skeleton';
```

On windows package.json my dependencies are these and all works fine:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2"
```

On Ubuntu it tells me that the lab is missing (and it is actually where the Skeleton should be, I do not know why on Windows it works despite not having the lab installed), so after I installed the lab the package.json on Ubuntu is this:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60"
```

And here is where I get the error I mentioned on the top.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because your `@material-ui/lab` is the latest version but the core is not the latest one. Upgrading `@material-ui/core` to 4.12.1 (or `latest`) version would solve this error.

Comment: Upgrading `@material-ui/core` to `4.12` and beyond causes a whole slew of other issues because Material UI started implementing a lot of upgrade console errors for v5. 

I have `@material-ui/core` locked on `4.11` and my `@material-ui/lab` is locked at `4.0.0`, when did this particular issue get introduced with the Skeleton component?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the Skeleton component. I upgraded `@material-ui/core` to `4.12.1` and the error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Buttons, I upgraded my libraries to the next versions then run `npm i`, restart the server and it works.

```
@material-ui/core: "4.11.4"
@material-ui/lab: "4.0.0-alpha.58"
@material-ui/icons: "4.11.2"
@material-ui/pickers: "3.3.10"
```